# Where can I find journal contents of Ars Combinatoria

Tags: co.combinatorics, journals

In the journal [website](http://combinatorialmath.ca/ArsCombinatoria/TOC.html), there are table of contents available only from 1995-2019. Where can I find the table of contents  before that?  And, is the journal only offline through subscription? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Small correction of English: "up to 1995" suggests "years before 1995" whereas I think you mean that there are only TOC going back as far as 1995

Comment: MathSciNet does show the issues going back to the start of the journal in 1976, but I admit this is a slow and inconvenient way to skim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tables of contents are not available online, but you can reconstruct them using Web of Science or MathSciNet (if you have access), or Google Scholar (query *source:"Ars Combinatoria"*).

It should not be too much work to recreate the listings for all missing years; for starters, here I have listed the [764 papers from the years 1985-1994](https://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/Ars_Combinatoria_1985_1994.html) (volumes 19 through 38).

Comment: Thanks for your effort! It seems you are more interested in Mathematics than physics!